# Steam OpenID doesn't work on my Centos 6 using Plesk 12

Tags: php, centos, openid, plesk, steam

My problem is that I'm trying to get Steam OpenID to work on my live server. It works great on localhost but as soon as I transition everything to my server and host the site, it doesn't work

**Description of the Problem:**

- I click on the login button
- it takes me to the steam login page
- I enter my credentials and login
- it takes my back to my site with following url:

> my.site.com/?login&openid.ns=http%253A%252F%252Fspecs.openid.net%252Fauth%252F2.0&openid.mode=id_res&openid.op_endpoint=https%253A%252F%252Fsteamcommunity.com%252Fopenid%252Flogin&openid.claimed_id=http%253A%252F%252Fsteamcommunity.com%252Fopenid%252Fid%252F76561198053526016&openid.identity=http%253A%252F%252Fsteamcommunity.com%252Fopenid%252Fid%252F76561198053526016&openid.return_to=http%253A%252F%252Fcsgofortunes.com%252F%253Flogin&openid.response_nonce=2015-09-10T21%253A38%253A33Z56koovUVTz1Az25Y8ag7MfjBwrs%253D&openid.assoc_handle=1234567890&openid.signed=signed%252Cop_endpoint%252Cclaimed_id%252Cidentity%252Creturn_to%252Cresponse_nonce%252Cassoc_handle&openid.sig=gyTXVAIWc1keaPH05Xgda8O9nHo%253D
>    - I'm back to original homepage without it displaying any user information
>    - it doesn't make use of the response like it does on my localhost

**FYI**

- $openid = new LightOpenID('my.site.com'); <-- this has been set appropriately as i switched to my server
- I have curled enabled
- I have a correct API key

**Possible leads towards finding a solution:**

- I think it might be my php, what settings would I need to modify so it can make use of the response from steam?

**EDIT**

So i looked at the response headers from localhost and from my server. On localhost, it states "Connection: Keep-alive" while on my server it states "Connection: close". How do I keep the connection alive?

**EDIT 2**

In my httpd.conf, I changed the following line "KeepAlive Off" to "KeepAlive On"; the change did allow the connection to be alive, however, it still doesn't use the response to display any user information.

**EDIT 3**

So my response query string parameters are as follows

server:

decoded:

> http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0

encoded:

> http%253A%252F%252Fspecs.openid.net%252Fauth%252F2.0

localhost:

decoded:

> http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0

enconded:

> http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0

As you can see the decoded version on my server is still encoded, how do I fix this issue?

Comment: So i looked at the response headers from localhost and from my server. On localhost, it states "Connection: Keep-alive" while on my server it states "Connection: close". How do I keep the connection alive?

Comment: You may want to include this information in your question or edit the question to indicate anything else you have tried.